# How to connect to a remote oracle database on an openshift node.js application?

Tags: node.js, oracle, openshift, node-oracledb

I have a `node.js` application that connects to a remote `Oracle` database. On my local machine, I use `node-oracledb` to connect to the db and it works well.

I am trying to deploy this node application on `OpenShift`. However, I am unable to get `node-oracledb` installed on `OpenShift`. I believe this is due to the prerequisite of having Oracle InstantClient downloaded and installed which is not an option in `OpenShift`.

Any ideas on how to get this working on `OpenShift`?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with OpenShift, but I assume you're using a Node.js service that they provide. I agree that the issue is likely the dependency on the InstantClient.

Does OpenShift support VMs? If so, you could go down to a lower level and build a VM that works for you.

Another option would be to use Oracle's Node.js service which supports the driver: https://cloud.oracle.com/en_US/acc

One last option would be to set up a restful API for the database (not sure where or how you'd do that as I don't know your infrastructure) and then communicate with that from OpenShift.